# change the parent class to another one simply doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I created a parent test case class. I want change the exising other test case from inheriting `XCTestCase` to `ParentTestCase`.

**ParentTestCase.m :**

```
@interface ParentTestCase : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation ParentTestCase

  - (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
  }

  - (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
  }
}
```

For example, I have another test case class, when I created it, I use default `XCTestCase` as its parent class. So, the code is like this:

```
                              // If I change this to ParentTestCase,
                              // I get error:
                              // "Can't find interface declaration for 'ParentTestCase'"
    @interface OtherTestCase : XCTestCase
    @end

    @implementation OtherTestCase

      - (void)setUp {
        [super setUp];
      }

      - (void)tearDown {
        [super tearDown];
      }
    }
```

If I directly change the parent class of above code to `ParentTestCase`,
I get compiler error:

```
"Can't find interface declaration for 'ParentTestCase'
```

But if I start from scratch, create a new test case class, in xcode popup window explicitly tell subclass from `ParentTestCase`. Then it is fine: 
[image]

Why directly changing parent class from existing code not working?

How to refactor the existing test class to inherit from another class in XCode?

**==== UPDATE ===**

For those who think I should import header, here is the class that is created from scratch:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface SomeOtherTest : ParentTestCase

@end

@implementation SomeOtherTest

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}
}
```

**There is no header import from XCode either.**

I also tried to import the header as some people suggested:

```
#import "ParentTestCase.h"
```

and I get error `'ParentTestCase.h' file not found`. I am not surprised about this error, because there is no public header file for unit test class.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you `@import` the new parent class?

Comment: @Putz1103, if you try you know, when creating Unit Test class, there is no header file, how to import? I mean there is only `ParentTestCase.m` , but no `ParentTestCase.h` file.

Comment: I've never done automated testing, sorry.  I was just checking for the obvious possibility.

Comment: @Putz1103 , it is also my first time doing unit testing in iOS. so, this problem sounds weird, but I really want to understand why I can't simply change the parent class name from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Putz1103 is right - you need to import the header to be able to use a subclass. If you generate a class from the popup shown in your question, isn't there an import statement at the top?

Test classes have the header and implementation in the same file simply because it is tidier (no need to have two files for every class, since you don't normally inherit). There's nothing stopping you manually creating a header file and importing it.

Add your parent class using the iOS / Source / Cocoa Touch Class template, and choose XCTestCase as the superclass. This will generate you a separate header and implementation file. You will then be able to import that header everywhere else.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried? No, there is no header import in the file created from scratch. XCode doesn't import that class either.  Please see my update.

Comment: Testing your problem here, the file created from scratch is created but immediately has compiler errors. You need to create and import a header

Comment: Again, are you sure? have you tried ? I get error "ParentTestCase.h file not found" in the line `#import "ParentTestCase.h"` after I added the import as you suggested. Like I said, there is no public header file created by xcode for unit test class.

Comment: I've updated the answer as well, it's simplest just to use the new class template so it makes the header for you